# sending a file in the soap/wsdl message under JBoss authorization, javax.ws annotations

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, wsdl, wildfly

I have a problem with sending a file using soap/wsdl message under JBoss authorization (@RolesAllowed and @SecurityDomain). The code below works as long as I do not activate annotations @SecurityDomain and/or @RolesAllowed. I did add a user to JBoss, all other web services work correctly (like saying "hello" or sending an array of objects), but this one (sending a file) throws errors immediately after I try to restore authorization. My current idea what might be the reason is the keystone because I get warn message when I start JBoss, but I tried to create it once and did not help at all (however, I may be doing it wrong). I also tried to manipulate security settings on WildFly admin console, but I do not know whether it allows changes to application level authentication. It did not help, anyway.

```
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain;
import org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext;

import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOM;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

@Stateless
@WebService
//@RolesAllowed("user") // < --if I put @PermitAll here, everything works ok
//@SecurityDomain("other")
//@WebContext(contextRoot="/lab-soa1c-soap", urlPattern="/*", authMethod="BASIC", transportGuarantee="NONE", secureWSDLAccess = false)
//@javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding(style= javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class FileSenderApache {

        //@PermitAll
        //@MTOM(enabled = true, threshold = 2048)
        @WebMethod(action = "apacheSend")
        @WebResult(name = "fileSent")

        public String Send (@WebParam(name = "path") String path){

            File file = new File(path);

            String encodedfile = null;
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                System.out.println((int) file.length());
                System.out.println(file.length());
                fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);

                byte[] apacheBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
                encodedfile = new String(apacheBytes);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                encodedfile = "File does not exist";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                encodedfile = "Sending error";
            }


            return encodedfile;

        }
}
```

This is the client side code:

```
import client.*;

import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.List;
import client.Course;

import client.Hello;
import client.HelloService;
import client.HelloWorld;
import client.HelloWorldService;
import client.ReceiveStudentArrayList;
import client.ReceiveStudentArrayListService;
import client.ReturnStudentHashMap2;
import client.ReturnStudentHashMap2Service;
import client.Student;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("-------------------PICTURE---------------------");

            FileSenderService fsas = new FileSenderService();
            FileSender fsa = fsas.getFileSenderPort();
            setCredentials((BindingProvider)fsa);
            String img = fsa.send("/Users/user/SOAP_KUBA_2/lab-soa1c/lab-soa1c-soap/pics/images-3.jpeg");
            DecodeToImage dec = new DecodeToImage();
            BufferedImage image = DecodeToImage.decode(img);
            new Painter(image);

            System.out.println("------------------END OF PICTURE-----------------");
        }

        private static void setCredentials(BindingProvider port) {
           port.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.security.auth.username", "user");
          port.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.security.auth.password", "user");
        }
    }
```

Here are additional classes on the client side:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

   public class Painter{
    BufferedImage image;

    public Painter(final BufferedImage image) throws Exception
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame editorFrame = new JFrame("Image Demo");
               editorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


                ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
                JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
                jLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
                editorFrame.getContentPane().add(jLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                editorFrame.pack();
                editorFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                editorFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Another one:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class MyPanel extends Panel {
    Image i;

    public void paintImage(Graphics g, Image i){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, 1920, 1200, Color.gray, null);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        paintImage(g,i);
    }

    public void setImage(Image i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

And the last one:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DecodeToImage {
    public static BufferedImage decode(String imageString){
        BufferedImage image = null;
        byte[] imageByte;
        try{
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
            image = ImageIO.read(bis);
            bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the error message that is thrown (when I try activate annotation @RolesAllowed("user").

```
Exception in thread "main"     com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public java.lang.String pl.edu.agh.kis.FileSenderApache.Send(java.lang.String) of bean: FileSenderApache is not allowed Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
    at     com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
    at     com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.send(Unknown Source)
    at pl.edu.kis.Main.main(Main.java:99)
```

Server logs:

```
12:12:44,768 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-19) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component FileSenderApache for method public java.lang.String   pl.edu.agh.kis.FileSenderApache.Send(java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public java.lang.String pl.edu.agh.kis.FileSenderApache.Send(java.lang.String) of bean: FileSenderApache is not allowed
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:137)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:169)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:145)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

12:12:44,775 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-19) Application {http://kis.agh.edu.pl/}FileSenderApacheService#{http://kis.agh.edu.pl/}Send has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public java.lang.String pl.edu.agh.kis.FileSenderApache.Send(java.lang.String) of bean: FileSenderApache is not allowed
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:145)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:298)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public java.lang.String     pl.edu.agh.kis.FileSenderApache.Send(java.lang.String) of bean: FileSenderApache is not allowed
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:137)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:169)
    at     org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    ... 61 more
```

Why adding @RolesAllowed("user") causes problems - all other web services work fine, but this one.

The problem is with this line:

```
String img = fsa.send("/Users/user/SOAP_KUBA_2/lab-soa1c/lab-soa1c-soap/pics/images-3.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a wrapper class. Path to the file is an attribute and the method that encodes the file is within the getter. When i call the getter it returns a picture encoded into a string. Web service sends an instance of an entire class and by using the getter i recover the picture.